# How to copy and paste rows from workbook to another with non consecutive rows

Tags: vba, excel

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

'## Open both workbooks first:
Set x = Workbooks.Open("Name of Copied Document")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("Name of Pasted Document")

'Now, copy what you want from x:
x.Sheets("Report Data").Range("A7:ax7").Copy

'Now, paste to y worksheet:
y.Sheets("Jan").Range("A7:ax7").PasteSpecial

'Close x:
x.Close

End Sub
```

I am using this code to copy and paste rows from existing data to another work book in the same respective row. I want to Copy from A7:AX7 and also from A23:ax23, but do not want the rows between. With the end result being the copied data goes in the same row that its on from X sheet to Y sheet.

Comment: Does your current code work for the range "A7:AX7"?

Comment: Yes. Current code does work @MatteoNNZ

Comment: Jason already gave you the answer below, it's enough to split the copy-paste.

Comment: I feel like I just saw this code yesterday...

Comment: Yep, I thought so... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27966854/copy-contents-from-one-excel-sheet-to-another-excel-sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way would just be to iterate over your operation ranges using a loop. This way you don't have to copy-paste code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

    Dim x As Workbook
    Dim y As Workbook

    '## Open both workbooks first:
    Set x = Workbooks.Open("Name of Copied Document")
    Set y = Workbooks.Open("Name of Pasted Document")

    Dim rangeCells As Variant
    For Each rangeCells In Split("A7:AX7,A23:AX23", ",")
        'Now, copy what you want from x:
        x.Sheets("Report Data").Range(rangeCells).Copy

        'Now, paste to y worksheet:
        y.Sheets("Jan").Range(rangeCells).PasteSpecial
    Next

    'Close x:
    x.Close

End Sub
```

Note how I am reusing the copy-paste code by identifying the range address using a comma separated string in the `Split` statement. If, for example, you wanted to add another copy range you can just add it to the end.

For example:

```
    ' Also add A50:AX50 to the copy-paste operation.
    For Each rangeCells In Split("A7:AX7,A23:AX23,A50:AX50", ",")
```

Comment: so a group has data from 1/1/15 in A7. Another group (in A23:AX23) is also 1/1/15, but as I add new rows (1/2/15, 1/3/15, etc.) A23:AX23 will move down. Is there a way to choose which cell the copied data can be pasted in? So A7 is constant, but A23 i'd like to choose a new row for.

Comment: @Moxdawg4 - This can certainly be done. You would just need to know what the row number is and you could build the string: `"A7:AX7,A" & row & ":AX" & row`